# mvc form cannot create an abstract class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form with 2 select box. But when I click the submit button, there's an error saying "Cannot create an abstract class". I have no idea what is going wrong here

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Admin")) { 
    <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-warning small-text custom-btn" />

    <div class="select-box">
        <select name="users[]" multiple size="35">@{ Html.RenderAction("UserList", "GroupsAndUsers"); }</select>
    </div>

     <div class="select-box"> 
        <p class="blue-text bold-text">Groups</p>
        <select name="group" size="35">@{ Html.RenderAction("GroupList", "GroupsAndUsers"); }</select>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="RedirectToUrl" value="~/GroupsAndUsers/AddUsers" />
}
```

Admin/Add

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(Array userIDs, int groupID, string RedirectToUrl)
        {

            return Redirect(RedirectToUrl);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array` is an abstract class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx), so MVC has no idea which specific Array implementation to create when binding the parameters. Try something like:

```
public ActionResult Add(int[] userIDs, int groupID, string RedirectToUrl)
```